# Is it a security risk to include a .git folder in the build step of a Docker multistage build?

Tags: git, docker

Is it a security risk to include a .git folder in the build step of a Docker multistage build?

To illustrate with an example. We have a compilation step using Java's maven build tool which reads git information, such as the tag and the commit. This requires the compile step to have access to the .git folder. Afterwards the resulting artifacts are copied to the final image. See:

```
FROM maven:3.5.4 as build
COPY $PWD /cbioportal
WORKDIR /cbioportal
RUN mvn -DskipTests clean install

FROM openjdk:8-jre
RUN mkdir -p /cbioportal
COPY --from=build /cbioportal/cbioportal*.war /app.war
COPY --from=build /cbioportal/webapp-runner.jar /webapp-runner.jar
```

If we share the resulting image publicly. Are there any ways to obtain information about the original .git folder the image was created from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .git will be cached on the computer which will build the image but wont be include in the final image, that will have only 3 layers added to the openkdk ones:
  - one layer with /cbioportal dir
  - one layer with the war file copied from build
  - one layer with the webapp-runner.jar

Using docker inspect, you can list the layers of the two images and compare...